# What's the word for technical/scientific/official terms?

Tags: single-word-requests

> I was beginning to think I was experiencing the Mandela effect, which has a rather unimaginative ____ [name|term]: false memory.

Is there either an adjective that fills the `____` that means scientific, official, and technical, or a noun that replaces `____ [name|term]`?  It would be a word that means *this is what experts in the field would call it in their discourse*.

"Technical" may, in fact, be the best word, but I was hoping for something a little less plebeian because I'm a snob.

Comment: “term of art”?  See for example https://www.dictionary.com/browse/term-of-art?s=t

Comment: I had never heard that phrase before.  It means exactly what I requested.  I just wish I liked the sound of it more.  

Comment: You could go the other way (less formal) and just call it a moniker.

Comment: [*Technical term*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/technical_term) is well understood.

Comment: This is going in a Facebook post.  I like to use the best-*sounding* phrases more than the most well understood.

Comment: Please decide if you want a noun, like label, or an adjective, like specialized.

Comment: @YosefBaskin why?  Either will work for my purposes.

Comment: A poster needs to decide what they are looking for, to gain the most cooperation on this site.

Comment: The concepts of technical terms, scientific terms, and official terms are **three different** concepts (although there are overlaps among them).

Comment: @jsw29 I didn't say x, y, or z.  I said x, y, *and* z.

Comment: In that case, the answer is that there is probably no such term, because there is unlikely to be an official term for it. For there to be an official term for something, there has to be some institutional authority that would make it official, and the question does not make it clear what such an authority would be in this case.

Comment: @dx_over_dt How is appellation "what experts in the field would call it in their discourse"? If that doesn't matter, which apparently it doesn't, I rather favored *moniker*, as suggested by pbasdf.

Comment: @RichardKayser you are right, when I marked it as the answer, in my head I was thinking "technical appellation", which is perfectly snooty enough.

Comment: Can it be ...unimaginative antimnemonics: false memory?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if "appellation" would humor your snobbery :)

Answer (score 0):

One adjective for this, although it applies to more than just those three words, is **domain specific**.

From ["What is Domain Specific Vocabulary?"](https://helpfulprofessor.com/domain-specific-vocabulary/) by Chris Drew:

> Domain specific vocabulary is the language that is used primarily within one area of knowledge but not others.
>
> Examples of areas or ‘domains’ of knowledge include: Chemistry, Mathematics, Literature, Medicine and History.
>
> The domain-specific vocabulary used by people in chemistry might include ‘molar ratios’, ‘element’, ‘compound’ and ‘substance’. These words have specific meaning to chemists and may not be understood by outsiders.
>
> Domain specific language is a marker of inclusion within a community of practice. People who are comfortable with the discourse of a particular domain and can converse using that language are able to have more detailed, nuanced and in-depth conversations than outsiders.

As such, *the Mandela effect* is a domain-specific term that relates to psychology.

To paraphrase the example sentence:

> I was beginning to think I was experiencing the Mandela effect, which has a rather unimaginative *domain-specific* term; in common use, it is "false memory."

Answer (score 0):

How about **accepted** or **consensus**? From M-W:

> **[accepted](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accepted)**: generally approved or used

> **[consensus](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/consensus)**: general agreement

Your example:

> I was beginning to think I was experiencing the Mandela effect, which has a rather unimaginative **accepted** name: false memory.

> I was beginning to think I was experiencing the Mandela effect, which has a rather unimaginative **consensus** name: false memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can also convey what you mean by reorganizing the clause to simply say it:

> I was beginning to think I was experiencing the Mandela effect, **for which the field has a rather airless term: *false memory*.**

> I was beginning to think I was experiencing the Mandela effect, **known in the field as the more pedestrian *false memory*.**

> I was beginning to think I was experiencing the Mandela effect, **which the field—less engagingly—terms *false memory*.**

As you can tell, I don't love *unimaginative* here. I'm sure the practitioners have plenty of imagination but would prefer to use straightforward terminology, whereas the layman would enjoy something more evocative.